# Component Placement Strategy for Regulator and Controller

Tags: pcb, switches, components, layout, ground-plane

I am reading this interesting document from TI [PCB Layout Considerations for Switchers](http://u.dianyuan.com/upload/space/2011/01/17/1295276197-397147.pdf)
It explains the issue of the return path for high di/dt currents in regulators. To summarize my understanding, it says that as the return current takes the path of the least impedance, so try to minimize the loop for high di/dt currents and separate it from the GND plane. That way, this current does not destroy your ground plane (modeled as RLC).
It introduces a simple way to find high di/dt in all topologies. For example in a buck regulator, we only need to draw the switch ON (green color) and OFF current path (red color). Any part of the circuit that has only a single color is a high di/dt path.

[image]

I am confused about the placement strategy after continuing reading, but let me just say what I think is the best place on PCB and why!

[image]

If I have all the loop components (Cap, high SW, low SW) on one layer and very close to each other, I would have the least impedance. So, the best place for the input capacitor is on the same layer.
I want to put the inductor on the other side to make it far from the Switching noisy node.

Please advise if you see any issue in my thoughts.

Comment: I like to think "power is the original differential signal" when I do SMPS layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the input cap will handle most of the HF current, the two current paths (switch on/red, off/blue) differ only in these two parts of the loop:

[image]

So your problems will be proportional to the area outlined in purple.

On the layout:

[image]

It's a pretty good placement.

You could put the inductor on the back if you wanted the ground connection of the output cap to be next to the input cap, to avoid injecting the inductor ripple current into your ground plane. If you hand solder, it's easy. If it's for fabrication, it'll cost extra. It'll also take up space on the back, so the enclosure will decide if it fits.

Unless your current is huge, consider shrinking the SW node trace. Its capacitance to ground is charged and discharged on each cycle, which wastes energy. However, the bottom MOSFETs are mostly cooled through their drain pins, which are on SW node, so you'd have to check thermals. If you use 2 FETs in parallel, I assume the current is going to be pretty high. If you want to stick a small heat sink on top of them, I think it should be grounded, otherwise it could make a nice radiating antenna.

Also if your current is high, maybe you need more than one input cap.

Answer (score 1):

The inductor should stay close to the switch node because:

Besides the primary objective of minimizing magnetic interference due to high-dI/dt loop size, the secondary objective is to minimize electric field interference from the high-dV/dt node. That latter node is the switch node, to which the inductor connects.

Therefore, do keep it close. And connect the inner winding (inductor pin 1) to the switch node.

That said, the backside can be good, but is usually not decisively better than a well packed single layer SMD design.

Comment: Thanks. I can see your point about the inductor. Adding a small inductance value to the trace of the inductor and the switching node is not a big deal. How about the input capacitor? You also think to place it on the same layer?

Comment: @chami input inductor is part of the high-dI/dt loop. Via inductance would be rather detrimental, so it goes on the top layer, with a close continuous Ground plane on L2 to reduce loop inductance further.

Comment: the confusing part about the attached link is that the way it says to find high di/dt loop, the inductor is not included. However, it says later (page 24) that starting with the switching node (power switch, diode, and inductor) and put a shape that covers all three pads! It makes more sense now if I consider the inductor in the high di/dt loop.

Comment: @chami The inductor pad 1 is part of the high-dV/dt **node**. The inductor is **not** part of the high-dI/dt **loop**.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes to add to the existing answers, in no particular order --

Paralleling transistors can be troublesome.  You get extra congestion routing the gate, and the inductance to each transistor is unmatched: notice the left pair are closer to the bypass cap than the right pair.

Note that parallel transistors should be driven with individual gate resistors.  This allows them to turn on at their respective threshold voltages, sharing current a bit better in the initial fraction of a microsecond after turn-on (and likewise at turn-off).

dI/dt is due to inductance.  You keep the supply loop short (input cap, transistor, diode) so that commutation can proceed quickly.  Commutation meaning, the transfer of current flow from +V to GND or vice versa.  These are separate connections, and so there is an inductance between them.

And to remark on that a bit briefly: inductance corresponds to length.  The inductivity of free space is about 1.257uH/m.  There is a geometry factor in there, it depends on how the conductors are arranged -- wide and closely spaced is better than thin and distant spaced -- but it's always proportional to the length of the structure.  So, a short, tight layout is better than a wide one.

We prefer low inductance, because we can switch faster, reducing switching losses.  Too much inductance slows switching, and causes high peak voltages (when gate drive is too fast compared to the loop's LC time constant).

Which, the LC time constant is the loop inductance and device capacitance.  Which one depends on rising or falling edge: remember they may be different, and typically are -- MOSFET into a diode, or dissimilar (synchronous) MOSFETs.

Inductor placement: it isn't very important.  Again, inductance defines dI/dt.  There's a literal inductor here, so dI/dt is far smaller than for the switching loop.  Notice the other answers are motivated by secondary concerns: electric field emission from the switch node, or simply the losses and potential interference associated with a long switch node trace.  There is nothing intrinsically bad with a long switch node trace -- these can be important considerations, but they are secondary to the operation of the switching loop.

So if you're having a hard time placing the inductor, it's not a big deal.  It can be placed further, but keep the other concerns in mind.

As example, I once designed a small SEPIC converter for a kind of control box under automotive standards.  In particular, the enclosure was plastic (potted for environmental and vibration immunity), so, no shielding value.  The switching node is slightly larger for SEPIC: two inductors are coupled together by a capacitor, so the switch node includes the transistor, diode, inductor(s) (they can be a coupled inductor pair, a single component) and capacitor.  I kept this minimal, but it still ran afoul of a particularly sensitive test -- I don't recall the standard and number unfortunately -- but it was a 1m E-field test, using a whip antenna with preamplifier placed near the EUT.  This is an unusual case, mind -- FCC/CE commercial tests do not involve this.  Expect to need unusual measures to meet unusual tests like this -- we solved it with a shield can, total overkill but eh it works -- but also, given a large enough switch node, maybe this would be a problem in a some-kW power supply for example, even at commercial test levels.

Back to parallel transistors.  If you find the balance is poor (some are getting much hotter, say?), you may be at the limit of what the layout can do.  Consider using multiple inverters, wired in parallel.  Typically phase-shifted, so they share input and output ripple currents somewhat -- phase interleave.  This way, although you spend a bit more hardware/cost with additional controllers/drivers, you can save on input/output filter caps, and the design can be surprisingly compact.  This is the only way to run at high power levels and high frequencies: at some point, you simply can't get the switching loop small enough, and even GaN MOSFETs won't save you.  Instead you need to use more channels in parallel, each individual channel being designed for that maximum capability.

Comment: About that last paragraph: a couple of years ago, I spoke to some guy from Infineon power electronics, and told him that the future needs more integrated half bridge ICs (ideally with integrated drivers) to minimize all these loop inductances and really reap GaN benefits. He agreed but I still can't see many products along these lines, one being the LMG5200. Are multiphase converters in the end just more worthwhile? (never made one myself)

Comment: @tobalt Probably both is good. GaN right now I think is more concentrating on lower power (where the loop inductance is still achievable e.g. eGaN dies) or high voltage (where more LL is permissible on account of higher voltage ratings). Neither really pushing frequencies all that hard AFAIK, but the lower Rds(on) and Coss loss are still valuable. As applications, and chip supplies, mature, perhaps bigger and more of these will come along.

Comment: @Tim Williams Thank you. Not sure about understanding this part:
“We prefer low inductance because we can switch faster, reducing switching losses”—Not having a faster switch means a higher switching loss?

Comment: @chami A faster switch incurs the hazard of excess peak voltage, if inductance is not also controlled.  Which either causes dissipation (with snubbing or if it's tolerant of avalanche) or failure (overvoltage, avalanche wear). That could probably be worded better, I agree...